# How do each of the sticky headers Flutter libraries render their content?

Tags: flutter, scroll, sticky

I have an app that will potentially have hundreds of elements within each group.

I am looking into different alternatives for sticky headers within these lists. I would like to know if any of these, or which ones, render the widgets as they show in view, same as *ListView.builder* does.

The alternatives I have come across are these:

- *[Grouped list package for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list)*

  *[flutter_sticky_header](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header)*

and

- *[Flutter Sticky Headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers)*

StickyHeaders does not seem to do the job, since each sticky header and their content are one element in *ListView.builder*.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Have you read about `Create lists with different types of items` https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/mixed-list  ?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77269364/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.